# After updating a cell and save excel, formulas based on this cell doesnt recalculate

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Hi,

Im using XML SDK to update some cells on an excel file.

This is the code that im using to update a cell for a given text (and its working fine).

```
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, sheetname);

spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;

spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;

    if (worksheetPart != null)
    {
       Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, columnName, rowIndex);
       cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);
       cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
       // Save the worksheet.
       worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
    }
```

For other hand now i want to open again the excel file and get the updated values from other cells whose formulas are based on the previous cell but even with the following lines im not able to do it:

```
spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;

spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
```

Do you know why im not getting the updated values?

Thanks

Regards.

Jose

Comment: What do you mean by "column text"? The text value of one cell in a column?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I meant I want to change the text of the column header.

Comment: based on the example in the link that you referenced, what text do you want to change...? please say what it is you want to change and to what Text..thanks

Answer (score 2):

Execute the below function for every cell that contains a formula.

```
public void ReCalcuateFormula(Cell cell)
{
    if (cell.CellFormula != null)
        cell.CellFormula.CalculateCell = new BooleanValue(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See Vincent's answer here:
[OpenXML - refresh Excel sheet after cell update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818508/openxml-refresh-excel-sheet-after-cell-update)

> Open XML SDK doesn't refresh the calculation results of formulas. Only
>   Excel does that (or other spreadsheet software). So even if you set
>   ForceFullCalculation and FullCalculationOnLoad to true, you only tell
>   Excel to force a full calculation and do it when loading the
>   spreadsheet file.
>
> This is why you always get the "old" value. Because there's no "new"
>   value to speak of.
>
> To test this, you can set the CellValue (of the Cell class) to say
>   "3.14159" with the CellFormula intact. Excel will calculate and
>   display the correct value of your formula, even though you
>   specifically set the cell value as "3.14159". [Unless of course, your
>   formula evaluates to PI...]
>
> To solve this, you either have a calculation engine to read in the
>   formula and calculate the result for you. Or save the spreadsheet and
>   run Excel (in Interop mode) to calculate all the formulas, but that
>   kind of defeat the purpose of using Open XML SDK in the first place.